# How to assign APL expression to execute on pressing shortcut?

Tags: apl, dyalog

I have Dyalog APL 13.2.20611.0 64 Unicode session, and I have utility function, which I want to run on pressing shortcut. How can I configure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I do it:

(this is all stored in a separate ns within ⎕SE)

```
∇ lx
 menpath←'⎕se.mb'

     :With (menpath,'.dls')⎕WC'menu'('Caption' '&Develop')('Posn'(⎕SE.mb.help.Posn-1))
             'L3'⎕WC'menuitem'('Caption'('Tool1',⎕AV[9+⎕IO],'Shift+F1'))('Event' 'Select' '⍎MyCleverfunction1')('Accelerator' 112 1)
             'L4'⎕WC'menuitem'('Caption'('Tool2',⎕AV[9+⎕IO],'Shift+F2'))('Event' 'Select' '⍎MoreCleverneww')('Accelerator' 113 1)
 :EndIf

∇
```

This function should be called in the ⎕SE.Create-Event.

Hope this helps.

Comment: BTW, I assume that this could also be done with UCMDs (which would be far more elegant and modular, because it wouldn't require changing the default session-files at all) - but have not verified. Will do so...when I have a little time...(This is old code from V9 and onwards, so it can well afford some modernization...)

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I had to remove ⎕SE.mb.help.Posn, because of VALUE ERROR. Could you, please, elaborate on 'This function should be called in the ⎕SE.Create-Event', not sure I understand what did you mean.

Comment: As far as I understand user command means entering something like ]MYCOMMAND and pressing 'Enter', which is not exactly what I need.

Comment: I used this to make sure the menu gets inserted before the "Help"-menu. If it causes an error, this is either because your session does not have Dyalogs Standard-Menu or because "Options > Object-Syntax > Expose props of session" is not checked. It should work if you do `('Posn'(('⎕SE.mb.help'⎕WG'Posn')-1) instead...

Comment: re. ]MYCOMMAND - sure, that is also not what I was thinking of. BUT if there is something like a UCMDs-lx (which I think should be there and I also think I once read this, but can't recall right now) then this could also be used to modify the session's menu - which (at least to me) feels more elegant, because there's no need to modify Dyalog's session-object (in order to add this Create-stuff)

Comment: Agreed :-). I hope you will recall where you have read that. I searched the web, but failed to find comprehensive documentation.

Comment: Actually I think the doc has gotten better and they seem to be doing a lot of work in that direction (and support@dyalog.com is very helpful whenever I ask), so I'm optimistic ;)

Answer (score 3):

In version 13.2 of Dyalog APL the ]usetup user command is called when APL starts. You can do whatever you want there. If you are running Windows you can change the SALT\spice\setup.dyalog file to your liking.

Comment: In my environment, it is not allowed to use SALT. Corporate policy. Is there any other way to tell Dyalog, that I want my shotrcut run some code? Also, when I run this user command I get an error: 
]usetup

VALUE ERROR

Comment: You could always just use the snippet I posted below and put it into a separate workspace that you load and execute before loading the one you're working on. 
Or can save the session with that modified menu - but you'd have to re-apply these mods whenever you get an upodated session-file...